# Create new file in folder Java

Tags: java, file, io

I create new file in new directory:

```
File logFile = new File("C:/test/test/test.txt");
logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
logFile.createNewFile();
```

And if I agin try create new file (whithout filename extension, only "test" file):

```
File logFile = new File("C:/test/test");
logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
logFile.createNewFile();
```

I get:

> FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code to give fileNotFoundException. Did you run the program in different users ?

Comment: I think, what problem in create object. I try create object with similar name of directory. I think problem in this, but i don't know how it's fix.

Comment: mkdirs() - First it will check the directory existence. if exists it returns false. So it is not problem if your directory already exists

Comment: Then i run "C:/test/test.txt" all work.

Comment: Are you doing something else . you might not have (Running user) permission to create file to get during FileNotFoundException ( Access Denied) . else are you sure this exception throws in this line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern versions of Windows, regular users don't have access to write to c:/ without administrative privileges.  Your code looks OK (in terms of the use of mkdirs()) but I think you're running into this problem.

Try creating a directory in c:\users\YourUserName instead -- this is an issue with your java program lacking administrative privileges to write to c:\

Comment: Problem is not this. I try create new file in D:/ and result is similar.

Comment: What user are you?  Are you sure you have write access to those folders?  Have you tried writing to your own user directory as I suggested?  The error you're getting is very straightforward: access denied means you lack the permissions to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: When i run first code, directory and file is created. This is mean, what i have access to create files, no?

Comment: Did you used the same user to execute next time ?

Comment: Yes. I think problem is not user.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `C:/test/test` is an existing directory, and `createNewFile` will fail on that. The exception has just a very misleading name, `FileNotFoundException`.

(Furthermore `createNewFile()` in general is not needed, but I take it, after that you only open the file for appending.)

Comment: "C:/test/test/ " is an existing directory . not C:/test/test/test . As per the code he given

Comment: @Joop Eggen. Even when you try to create file C:/test/test - it would return false and will not through FileNotFoundException ( atleast in java 7)

Comment: Yes. mkdirs return false. But problem in logFile.createNewFile(). If first create "C:\test\test\test.txt", then try create "C:\test\test" folder, when i see Exception: The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: even the createNewFile would return false, if you are giving folder path